# How do i Pass username and password in an api url

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, url

I have an app that is secured by spring security. 
And i have added `BasicAuthInterceptor`. But when i request a rest api url to  server, i see the html login page instead of the json.
So am thinking maybe to pass username and password in url for requested api.But i don't know how. Any ideas/advice is very much appreciated. cheers!

THIS IS MY `BasicAuthInterceptor` Class

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( BasicAuthInterceptor.class );

private final String username;
private final String password;

public BasicAuthInterceptor( String username, String password ) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {

   // code here ...
}
```

AND AM TESTING WITH A CLIENT APP IN THE MAIN():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    //Get a new Rest-Template
    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    //Create and initialize the interceptor
    final List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add( new BasicAuthInterceptor( "admin", "admin" ) );
    template.setInterceptors( interceptors );

    //Do your request as normal
    final String helloResponse = template.getForObject( "http://localhost:9000/api/brands", String.class );

    System.out.println(helloResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the authentication type you are using server side.

For example, for basic authentication you need to add to the request headers a specific header named `Authorization` with this content

`Basic [TOKEN]`

where `[TOKEN]` stands for

`Base64(username:password)`

ie, username and password concatenated by a ':' and all encoded in Base64.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)

All this should be done (in your code) in the method `intercept`.

You can access the headers through the `HttpRequest` object (see documentation @ https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpRequest.html)

If you're using something different from basic authentication, then just Google and search for the correct header to add.

Comment: @RanzyBlessings glad it helped :-) May you consider accepting the answer, in case? thanks.